# Ruby bundle install: An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundle, bundler, devkit

I'm trying to run bundle install on my windows 10x64 and I keep getting this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161109-14104-1y5ai00.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
make "DESTDIR="

make failed, uncaught signal 11

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I'm using Ruby version 2.3.1. I have installed the right version of Ruby DevKit and rails version '4.2.6'

If I comment out web-console in the Gemfile I get a new error:

```
 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.6/ext/byebug
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161109-9448-8vnaze.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.6/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.6/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="

make failed, uncaught signal 11

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.0.6 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/byebug-9.0.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing byebug (9.0.6), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '9.0.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After also commenting out 'byebug' gem the bundle install works fine. 
I have reinstalled ruby and devkit and nothing seems to help.

The problem occured after I installed and ,soon after finding out it doesn't work for me, uninstalled ruby 2.2.5 and then reinstalled the 2.3.1 version. After uninstalling ruby 2.2.5 I also deleted the according ruby folder.

My classmates got it working so after spending so many hours on these errors I would also like to know the reason why these errors occure and maybe how to solve them?